# Как вывести словарь json на локальном сервере python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

Вот мой код примитивного сервера:

```
import http.server
import socketserver

PORT = 8080
Handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

with socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler) as httpd:
    print("serving at port", PORT)
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

как подключить к нему json файл так, что бы доступ к данным был не по http://localhost:8080/db.json, а по http://localhost:8080/data

json файл:

```
{
    "data": {
        "barcode": "1234587867678",
        "weight": "3",
        "volume": "0.9",
        "length_": "8",
        "width": "2",
        "height": "9",
        "uniqueIndex": "555"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import json
import http.server
import socketserver

PORT = 8080


class Handler(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path == '/data':
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header("Content-type", "application/json")
            self.end_headers()
            with open('data.json') as json_data:
                json_data = json.load(json_data)

            self.wfile.write(bytes(json.dumps(json_data), "utf8"))
            return

        return super().do_GET()


with socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler) as httpd:
    print("serving at port", PORT)
    httpd.serve_forever()
```